# Java Iterator backed by network connection

Tags: java, iterator

With some frequency I find myself writing APIs that offer an `Iterator<Foo>` which is backed by a network connection.  The implementation opens a network connection, reads information off the stream, and deserializes that information into `Foo`s to pass on to the caller.  Unfortunately there is always the possibility of an `IOException` and also the need to close the network connection gracefully (that can be made automatic when the caller reads the last `Foo`, but what if that doesn't happen?).

There are already a couple of questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346978/how-should-iterator-implementation-deal-with-checked-exceptions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450138/how-to-add-throws-exception-clause-when-implementing-a-method-defined-in-a-inter)) about how to deal with checked exceptions that would be thrown in an implementation of `Iterator`, and the accepted advice is "wrap them in unchecked `RuntimeException`s".  Meanwhile to allow closing the network connection we can implement `Closeable`.  So we end up with something like this for a well-behaved exception-checking caller:

```
Iterator<Foo> iter = null;
try {
    iter = getFooIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Foo foo = iter.next();
        // do something with foo
    }
}
catch(RuntimeException e) {
    if(e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
       // do something with the IOException
    }
    else throw e;
}
finally {
    if(iter instanceof Closeable) try { ((Closeable)iter).close(); } catch(IOException e) {}
}
```

And it seemed like such a nice idea to implement `Iterator`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you're working with Java 7 you could also consider using `AutoCloseable` and open the resources in the try statement, e.g. `try(iter = getFooIterator();) { ... } ` (the iterator would have to implement `AutoCloseable` though).

Comment: You might also want to consider closing the connection in the iterator's methods (e.g. in `next()` or `hasNext()`) and then throw an exception. That way the user of the iterator would not have to worry about closing the iterator (and thus the underlying connection) and just would have to handle the exception.

Comment: Have to admit that I am not a big Iterator guy (I use Collections and simple arrays a ton).  Why do you want to return an Iterator, with these open-ended questions, instead of a Collection, which would be a simpler API?  You get back the Collection, and everything is closed and any Exceptions that are going to happen happen.  I think I know the answer, but want to ask...

Comment: With an `Iterator` the caller can get to work on the `Foo`s right away.  That could make a significant difference if there are 1000s of `Foo`s coming over a slow network connection.

Comment: That's what I thought.  You could return a Collection that is a BlockingQueue.  But not sure if that would make much of a difference compared to an Iterator.

Comment: `BlockingQueue` is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the first step would be to wrap it up in an implementation- or app-specific exception, eliminating the need for catching generic `RuntimeException`s or checking the root cause.

I'd consider a specific implementation to avoid the closeable check and to wrap up the `IOException`.

```
NetworkIterator<Foo> iter = null;
try {
    iter = getFooIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Foo foo = iter.next();
        // do something with foo
    }
} catch (NetworkIteratorExceptiom e) {
    // do something with the IOException
} finally {
    iter.close();
}
```

I probably *wouldn't* give it method to make the boilerplate go away, but I'd be tempted; roughly:

```
NetworkIterator<Foo> iter = new IteratorThang<Foo>() {
    @Override public void each(Foo foo) {
        // Do something with foo
    }
};
```

Comment: Good ideas.  In fact, I wonder if there is any real benefit to even implementing `java.util.Iterator`, instead of having a specific Iterator-alike which can throw checked exceptions.  Are there many consumers of `Iterator`s?

Comment: @RobertTupelo-Schneck All sorts of things consume iterators; consider something like [Guava's `any` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8991373/438992)--there are lots of usecases for lazy iteration like this. It's basically the same as long computations that don't generate subsequent values until they're actually required (possibly caching)--it's just from the network instead of math (or whatever).